# finding/checking element exists in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains approx 13 items.

What I'm looking to do, is to find the 10th item in the array and display it.

The output from `var_dump` is:

```
array(13) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2)  etc etc
```

Ideally, I'd like to check if the 10th element exists first and if it does, display, it.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want the element with index 9 (or 10 if you get the question wrong), or the 10th element of array? An array like so:

     $arr = Array([1]=>1,[5]=>1,[9]=>1,[10]=>1...)

have $arr[9] != to effective 10th element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(array_key_exists(10, $arr)) {
  echo $arr[10];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($array[9])) echo $array[9];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo isset($array[9]) ? $array[9] : null;
```

that should work

or

```
if(isset($array[9]))
    echo $array[9];
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(isset($array[9])) {
echo $array[9];
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($array[9])) echo $array[9];
```